# How to get playwright execution reports back from docker container deployed in ECS via Github Actions

Tags: dockerfile, github-actions, amazon-ecs, playwright-test

Ok Long story short, my employer doesn't want to use server provided by Github to run playwright automation tests and since we are heavily invested in AWS, so expectedly we want to make use of capabilities of self hosted runners to achieve this.
Possible solutions through which this can be achieved :

1. Get an EC2 instance and perform everything there
2. Use Docker to put the code in container and then make use of ECR + ECS to deploy container for execution (Either EC2 or Fargate)
3. Containerise the code and put it up to LAMBDA (need to run shorter suits so that everything gets completed in under 15 mins)
4. Containerise the code and make use of EKS (where we either deploy container at run time or use any existing container to run the automation)

I've very new to whole thing (except the automation code) and this is getting overwhelming for me. Also, i'm unable to figure out how Execution Results + Logs will be rallied back to Github run post execution.

Apologies for a bit longer post without any code, but this Action template doesn't seems to be working out for :

```
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      if: always()
      with:
        name: playwright-report
        path: playwright-report/
        retention-days: 30
```

Looking out for help / suggestions :

1. How to get the results + log files back from container in AWS to Github post execution but before container destroys
2. Which approach out of 4 seems to be good, in terms of being cost effective and being flexible to launch multiple executions at will apart from nightly

Trying to do a POC using a sample repo to push the container with sample playwright test into ECS (https://github.com/irahul/sample_playwright_test/tree/main/.github/workflows/aws.yml) and looking for suggestions for the report part which i'm yet to implement.

Thanks !